# What is the more efficient way to read values from a file?

Tags: c++, graph, ifstream

I am trying to solve a problem which needs a graph representation. The graph nodes and edges information is extracted from a file. So far I have implemented a simple structure for the node:

```
struct Node {
    unsigned long long id;
    vector< pair<Node*, unsigned long long> > paths;
};
```

A function to add edges:

```
void add_path (vector<Node> &graph, unsigned long long id_1, unsigned long long id_2, unsigned long long distance){
    graph[id_1].paths.push_back({&graph[id_2], distance});
}
```

A function to initialise the graph the way the problem asks to:

```
vector<Node> generate_graph(unsigned long long n, vector<Node> &graph){
    graph[1].paths.push_back({&graph[2], 0});
    for(unsigned long long i = 2; i < graph.size(); ++i){
        graph[i].id = i;
        graph[i].paths.push_back({&graph[i+1], i});
        graph[i].paths.push_back({&graph[i-1], 0});
    }
    return graph;
}
```

And a main function that will read values from the file, and generate the appropriate graph for each of the cases.

```
int main(){
    ifstream file_input ("5.input", ifstream::in);
    ofstream file_output ("5.output", ofstream::out);

    int n_cases;
    file_input >> n_cases;
    for(int cas = 1; cas <= n_cases; ++cas){

        unsigned long long n_levels;
        file_input >> n_levels;
        cout << "starting case: " << cas << " --> " << n_levels << endl;
        vector<Node> graph(n_levels+2);
        generate_graph(n_levels, graph);

        unsigned long long shortcuts;
        file_input >> shortcuts;
        unsigned long long id_1, id_2, distance;
        for(unsigned long long n_short = 0; n_short < shortcuts; ++n_short){
            file_input >> id_1 >> id_2 >> distance; // <--- here seems to be the problem
            add_path(graph, id_1, id_2, distance);
        }
        //file_output << "Case #" << cas << ": " << a_star(graph, 1, n_levels) << endl;


    }

    file_input.close();
    file_output.close();
}
```

5.input contains around 800 different cases. One of the cases has 1013719052 nodes and 1943 edges (shortcut loop). When the program arrives at this point it simply keeps there thinking forever. My guess is that there is a more efficient way to read the input values and that will solve my problem.

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Edit:

Seems the problem is when generating the graph, too many nodes make the process slow.

Comment: Doing anything a billion times will take a while. What happens if you add a `cout << n_count;` every million reads, or so?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @BoPersson. Although the number of nodes is quite big this are not read from the file. The only thing that I read is the number of shortcuts (or additional edges, 1943). I didn't thought that reading 1943*3(start node, end node, distance) from a file would take so long. I can print n_short every 500 reads and let you know anyway.

Comment: @BoPersson sorry. It seems that what is taking a long time is generating the graph. My mistake, I will see how to solve that! thanks.

Comment: I would highly recommend using typedefs like `typedef uint64_t distance_t` and `typedef uint64_t id_t` to make the code more clear.  Also, `ifstream::in` is unnecessary when constructing an `ifstream` (likewise out), and `close()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you able to change the format of the input file?

Comment: @JohnZwinck thanks for the advice, I will change the format. And not, i am not able to change the format of the input file.